# Apple's SimplePing doesn't work over 3G

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using Apple's SimplePing to ping a host on iPhone. I expect the following delegate methods to work.

```
(1) - (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didSendPacket:(NSData *)packet;
(2) - (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet;
(3) - (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceiveUnexpectedPacket:(NSData *)packet;
(4) - (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailToSendPacket:(NSData *)packet error:(NSError *)error;
```

The results are...

1. **Simulator**: Methods (1) & (2 or 3 or 4) get called (correct)
2. **Device** (Using WiFi): Methods (1) & (2 or 3 or 4) get called (correct)
3. **Device** (Using 3G): Only methods (1) gets called. (incorrect, I expect (2 or 3 or 4) to also get calleA)

I tried some apps ([Network Ping Lite](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/network-ping-lite/id289967115?mt=8), [Free Ping](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/free-ping/id430758871?mt=8), [Ping Free](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ping-free/id430640666?mt=8)) available in AppStore. Their result is similar to mine.

I wan't to know if this is a bug in the SimplePing sample code by Apple or are there some other configurations I need to do?

**Below is the code i've used**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.simplePing = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    [self.simplePing setDelegate:self];
    [self.simplePing start];
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didStartWithAddress:(NSData *)address {
    [self.simplePing sendPingWithData:nil];
}
```

Comment: yes, some phone carries doesn't support ping over the 3G network.

Comment: Is there a way I can validate your point? In other words, how can I determine if the the carrier supports Ping.

Comment: simply: you can't validate that a specific carrier supports or not supports a ping over the mobile network.

Comment: @meccan You should add that as an answer.

Comment: @meccan: Your point is valid. I tested with two more carriers and I was able to ping. The same results showed on Android phones as well. Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**simply:**

you can't validate that a specific carrier supports or not supports a ping over the mobile network.